# Extract and split string in ansible

Tags: regex, split, ansible, ip, extract

I have a machine where the variable contains the a number that I want to extract and then split to build an IP address using ansible.

```
variable = machine240dev
```

I want to be able to extract 240 then split it to fill in the two middle octets of an ip address

e.g. `10.2.40.170`

I have tried various ways such as:

```
var: machine240dev

10.{{  var | regex_replace('[^0-9]','')[0] }}.{{ var | regex_replace('[^0-9]','')[-2:] }}.170
```

which fails as it doesn't like the `[0]` after the regex_replace filter.

I was just wondering if anyone has done this before or know a clean way to do it.

EDIT:

I have set a fact to first set the variable for the vlan before extracting the specific parts of the string.

```
- name: Setting vlan fact
  set_fact: vlan="{{  var | regex_replace('[^0-9]','') }}"
```

Then in my template i set:

```
IPADDR=10.{{ vlan[0] }}.{{ vlan[-2:] }}.170
```

However I am still open to suggestions on how this could be improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `regex_replace` solution like:

```
10.{{  var | regex_replace('.*([0-9])([0-9]{2}).*', '\\1.\\2') }}.170
```

Here,

- `.*` - matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `([0-9])([0-9]{2})` - Captures a digit into Group 1 and then two digits into Group 2
- `.*` - matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

The `\1.\2` replacement replaces the matched string with Group 1 + `.` + Group 2 values.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/otcFys/1).

Or, a `regex_search` based solution:

```
10.{{  var | regex_search('[0-9]') }}.{{ var | regex_search('(?<=[0-9])[0-9]{2}') }}.170
```

Output:

```
10.2.40.170
```

Here,

- `regex_search('[0-9]')`  extracts the first digit
- `regex_search('(?<=[0-9])[0-9]{2}')` - extracts two digits after a digit.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible allows you to create intermediate variables with the scope of the task, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        IPADDR: "10.{{ vlan[0] }}.{{ vlan[-2:] }}.170"
      vars:
        vlan: "{{ var | regex_replace('[^0-9]','') }}"
```